# String or binary data would be truncated. Is it something wrong with declaring "imagelocation"?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Currently I'm developing a student portal with an appropriate and simple login system for my college's final year project purpose. This is one of the command button (to save photo to SQL server) I've encountered error. This is the error statement:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.'

```vb
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    'String imagelocation = ""

    Dim images() As Byte = Nothing
    'Dim imagelocation As String
    'imagelocation = ""
    Dim Stream As New FileStream(imagelocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim brs As New BinaryReader(Stream)
    images = brs.ReadBytes(CInt(Stream.Length))

    Dim source As String = "Data Source=LAPTOP-85ALBAVS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Portal;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(source)
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As String = "Insert into Photo Values('" + TextBox2.Text + "', @images)"


    Dim qry As New SqlCommand(cmd, con)
    qry.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@images", images))

    'qry.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@images", pictureBox1));
    ***Dim i As Integer = qry.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If i >= 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successfull!", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Fail!", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
 End Sub
End Class
```

This is a SQL table for me to save the uploaded photo into database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Table]

**UPDATE**

Previously`Photo`column name changed to`Img`, `Photo`would be the table name.

So I tried to switch the code into another method which is:

```vb
    Dim source As String = "Data Source=LAPTOP-85ALBAVS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Portal;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(source)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Insert into Photo (Img, Pname) Values (@Img, @Pname)", con)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)

    command.Parameters.Add("@Img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray()
    command.Parameters.Add("@Pname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
    con.Open()

    If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully uploaded", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Failed. Try again.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
```

So it's actually worked I guess. Not sure if there would be any hidden error. Any comment would be helpful guys. This is the output of `Photo` table.
[`Photo`table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkB7r.jpg)

Comment: That is way too much code to be posting.  You need to spend some time on the issue yourself and narrow it down somewhat and then post ONLY the relevant code.

Comment: As @jmcilhinney said, you need to debug your code and step through it to identify which statement is causing the exception to be thrown, and just post the code that's relevant to that statement. In addition, I'd recommend doing some reading on parameterised SQL statements as, at present, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Can you provide data type of every columns inside `Photo` table? Also you're seem using concatenation for query string, use parameters instead.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes the image link titled "Table" is the data type for `Photo` table. Since I've never learn about parameter, that is why I'm not using it.

Comment: You would not need a legend to the controls if you gave them meaningful names. Pity the poor person who has to maintain your code.

Comment: @Mary I'm sorry for the trouble. Since I am the one developing it, I presume using default names for the buttons are easier for me. I mentioned the legend just for reference, as I mistakenly uploaded the whole paragraph of code which is not recommended. I will not repeat this mistake again. Thanks :)

Comment: This is the second time in as many days that this overload of the constructor for Parameters showed up. `qry.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@images", images))` This is the equivalent of .AddWithValue which caused your exception. (see answer by @Tetsuya Yamamoto ) Use the .Add method overload that requires a data type and size.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you specify a the size of a parameter and then provide data that is larger than that.  For a start, the way you're adding the parameter is bad:

```vb
qry.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@images", images))
```

You're not specifying a data type or a size there so you're relying on the system default type being OK.  Obviously it is not or you would not be getting this error.  ALWAYS specify the data type and, if the data type is variable-size, the size as well, e.g.

```vb
qry.Parameters.Add("@images", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = images
```

The `SqlDbType` value you specify should match the data type of the column the data is for and the size should match the size in the database too.  If you use `varbinary(max)` in the database then use -1 for the parameter size.

Comment: In fact, there is only issue with the codes for `button8`, the rest is fine. I'm posting the whole paragraph of codes in case just for further reference. The photo is intended to upload to `Photo` table. As enclosed screenshot `Table` is the data type I'm using for `Photo` table.

Comment: "the rest is fine. I'm posting the whole paragraph of codes in case just for further reference".  Don't.  If we need more we can ask for it but you should be posting only the code that is directly relevant to the issue.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that the `image` data type is deprecated so there's no good reason for you to be using it in a new database.  You should be using `varbinary`.  Regardless, if you are using `image` then you should still be specifying that as the data type for the parameter.  Because you are using a `Byte` array it will almost certainly be defaulting to `SqlDbType.VarBinary` and also using some default size (probably 4000 or 8000) and your data must be exceeding that size.  If you do as I have already told you to and be specific about the data type and size then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that `IMAGE` data type usage is deprecated. Usage of `VARBINARY(MAX)` is more recommended:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN Photo VARBINARY(MAX)
```

The explanation about image data type deprecation can be seen [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6519.storing-images-and-photos-in-sql-server.aspx).

> For storing images you have to make use of the varbinary(MAX)
>   datatype. The image datatype will be deprecated.

Next, the exception occurred because you're adding data to image column which has smaller size than passed image from parameter (because `SqlDbType` is not specified, CLR infers `Byte(n)` type automatically; hence data truncation may occur to fit passed array for `IMAGE` data type). Use `SqlDbType.VarBinary` with size set to `-1`:

```vb
qry.Parameters.Add("@images", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = images
```

Note that you can set maximum size of `VARBINARY` with certain numbers in bytes (other than `-1`), but you need to check against `images.Length` to prevent truncation (simply cancel upload process if image size is larger than specified).

```vb
If images.Length > 1048576 Then ' maximum limit e.g. 1 MiB
   ' cancel upload
Else
   ' continue and save to DB
End If
```

Finally, adjust the query to use parameters for all values:

```vb
Dim source As String = "Data Source=LAPTOP-85ALBAVS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Portal;Integrated Security=True"
Using con As New SqlConnection(source)
   con.Open()

   Dim cmd As String = "Insert into Photo Values(@pname, @images)"

   Using qry As New SqlCommand(cmd, con)
      qry.Parameters.Add("@pname", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
      qry.Parameters.Add("@images", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = images
      Dim i As Integer = qry.ExecuteNonQuery()

      ' other stuff

   End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Okay, so I have adjusted the specific query you've mentioned and using `varbinary` data type for `images`, set the size to `-1`. However, there is a error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'`with this query: `Dim i As Integer = qry.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto From the link you provided "Varbinary(max) can only store images with a maximum size of 2 GB." But your comment says "' maximum limit e.g. 1 MiB" Is this some other criteria that further restricts the 2GB limit?